# Cannot install Anaconda on my computer: Failed to Extract Packages Error

Tags: installation, module, package, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda on Win7. I have done this multiple times with no issue. The pc is a clone of others, lots of space, Win7, no issues, etc.

I am running 202309-64 bit setup.exe downloaded from Anaconda’s website.

It almost finishes installing, then I receive the error message “Failed to load packages.” I have tried clicking retry to no avail, abort cancels installation, and Ignore takes me to the next error message "Failed to link extracted packages to C:\Users\ME\anaconda3. Please check logs.

I have re-downloaded the installer, I have deleted all instances and files of anaconda and .condarc on my PC, and followed other troubleshooting steps including restarting my pc, checking disk space, removing all files of anything “conda”, installing as administrator with privileges to a different (Default) user account, etc. Always the same error occurs when I launch the installer.

Below is the log file I have. Please help!! Why won’t it install? How can their own installer not work properly, I am not doing anything odd, it should have the .dll file it is looking for no?

skipping to the bottom of the file…

```
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\yapf-0.31.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\yarl-1.8.1-py311h2bbff1b_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\ypy-websocket-0.8.2-py311haa95532_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zeromq-4.3.4-hd77b12b_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zfp-1.0.0-hd77b12b_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zict-2.2.0-py311haa95532_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zipp-3.11.0-py311haa95532_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zlib-1.2.13-h8cc25b3_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zlib-ng-2.0.7-h2bbff1b_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zope-1.0-py311haa95532_1\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zope.interface-5.4.0-py311h2bbff1b_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zstandard-0.19.0-py311h2bbff1b_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs\zstd-1.5.5-hd43e919_0\info
Extract: repodata_record.json
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\pkgs
Extract: python-3.11.5-he1021f5_0.conda
Extract: blas-1.0-mkl.conda
Extract: ca-certificates-2023.08.22-haa95532_0.conda
Extract: icc_rt-2022.1.0-h6049295_2.conda
Extract: mathjax-2.7.5-haa95532_0.conda
Extract: msys2-conda-epoch-20160418-1.tar.bz2
Extract: pybind11-abi-4-hd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: tzdata-2023c-h04d1e81_0.conda
Extract: vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2.conda
Extract: winpty-0.4.3-4.conda
Extract: m2-msys2-runtime-2.5.0.17080.65c939c-3.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2.tar.bz2
Extract: vc-14.2-h21ff451_1.conda
Extract: abseil-cpp-20211102.0-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: aom-3.6.0-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: aws-c-common-0.6.8-h2bbff1b_1.conda
Extract: bzip2-1.0.8-he774522_0.conda
Extract: c-ares-1.19.1-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: cfitsio-3.470-h2bbff1b_7.conda
Extract: charls-2.2.0-h6c2663c_0.conda
Extract: dav1d-1.2.1-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: fmt-9.1.0-h6d14046_0.conda
Extract: gflags-2.2.2-ha925a31_0.conda
Extract: giflib-5.2.1-h8cc25b3_3.conda
Extract: icu-58.2-ha925a31_3.conda
Extract: intel-openmp-2023.1.0-h59b6b97_46319.conda
Extract: jpeg-9e-h2bbff1b_1.conda
Extract: jq-1.6-haa95532_1.conda
Extract: kaleido-core-0.2.1-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: lerc-3.0-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: libaec-1.0.4-h33f27b4_1.conda
Extract: libbrotlicommon-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7.conda
Extract: libdeflate-1.17-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: libiconv-1.16-h2bbff1b_2.conda
Extract: liblief-0.12.3-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: libsodium-1.0.18-h62dcd97_0.conda
Extract: libspatialindex-1.9.3-h6c2663c_0.conda
Extract: libwebp-base-1.3.2-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: libzopfli-1.0.3-ha925a31_0.conda
Extract: lz4-c-1.9.4-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: lzo-2.10-he774522_2.conda
Extract: m2-patch-2.7.5-2.tar.bz2
Extract: openssl-3.0.10-h2bbff1b_2.conda
Extract: pcre-8.45-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: re2-2022.04.01-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: reproc-14.2.4-hd77b12b_1.conda
Extract: snappy-1.1.9-h6c2663c_0.conda
Extract: sqlite-3.41.2-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: tbb-2021.8.0-h59b6b97_0.conda
Extract: tk-8.6.12-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: utf8proc-2.6.1-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: xxhash-0.8.0-h2bbff1b_3.conda
Extract: xz-5.4.2-h8cc25b3_0.conda
Extract: yaml-0.2.5-he774522_0.conda
Extract: yaml-cpp-0.7.0-hd77b12b_1.conda
Extract: zfp-1.0.0-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: zlib-1.2.13-h8cc25b3_0.conda
Extract: zlib-ng-2.0.7-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: aws-checksums-0.1.11-h2bbff1b_2.conda
Extract: dal-2023.1.1-h59b6b97_48681.conda
Extract: glib-2.69.1-h5dc1a3c_2.conda
Extract: glog-0.5.0-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: hdf5-1.12.1-h51c971a_3.conda
Extract: krb5-1.20.1-h5b6d351_0.conda
Extract: libavif-0.11.1-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: libbrotlidec-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7.conda
Extract: libbrotlienc-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7.conda
Extract: libclang13-14.0.6-default_h8e68704_1.conda
Extract: libevent-2.1.12-h56d1f94_1.conda
Extract: libpng-1.6.39-h8cc25b3_0.conda
Extract: libprotobuf-3.20.3-h23ce68f_0.conda
Extract: libssh2-1.10.0-he2ea4bf_2.conda
Extract: libxml2-2.10.4-h0ad7f3c_1.conda
Extract: mkl-2023.1.0-h6b88ed4_46357.conda
Extract: pcre2-10.42-h0ff8eda_0.conda
Extract: reproc-cpp-14.2.4-hd77b12b_1.conda
Extract: zeromq-4.3.4-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: zstd-1.5.5-hd43e919_0.conda
Extract: aws-c-event-stream-0.1.6-hd77b12b_6.conda
Extract: blosc-1.21.3-h6c2663c_0.conda
Extract: brotli-bin-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7.conda
Extract: c-blosc2-2.8.0-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: freetype-2.12.1-ha860e81_0.conda
Extract: grpc-cpp-1.48.2-hfe90ff0_1.conda
Extract: libarchive-3.6.2-hb62f4d4_2.conda
Extract: libboost-1.82.0-hae598e9_1.conda
Extract: libclang-14.0.6-default_hb5a9fac_1.conda
Extract: libcurl-8.1.1-h86230a5_0.conda
Extract: libpq-12.15-h906ac69_1.conda
Extract: libsolv-0.7.24-h23ce68f_0.conda
Extract: libtiff-4.5.1-hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: libxslt-1.1.37-h2bbff1b_1.conda
Extract: menuinst-1.4.19-py311h59b6b97_1.conda
Extract: orc-1.7.4-h623e30f_1.conda
Extract: aiofiles-22.1.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: aiosqlite-0.18.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: alabaster-0.7.12-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: anaconda-anon-usage-0.4.2-py311hfc23b7f_0.conda
Extract: appdirs-1.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: async-timeout-4.0.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: atomicwrites-1.4.0-py_0.conda
Extract: attrs-22.1.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: aws-sdk-cpp-1.8.185-hd77b12b_1.conda
Extract: backcall-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: backports-1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: boltons-23.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: boost-cpp-1.82.0-h59b6b97_1.conda
Extract: brotli-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7.conda
Extract: certifi-2023.7.22-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: chardet-4.0.0-py311haa95532_1003.conda
Extract: charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: cloudpickle-2.2.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: colorama-0.4.6-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: console_shortcut-0.1.1-4.conda
Extract: constantly-15.1.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: cssselect-1.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: curl-8.1.1-h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: cycler-0.11.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: debugpy-1.6.7-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: decorator-5.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: defusedxml-0.7.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: diff-match-patch-20200713-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: dill-0.3.6-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: docstring-to-markdown-0.11-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: docutils-0.18.1-py311haa95532_3.conda
Extract: entrypoints-0.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: executing-0.8.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: filelock-3.9.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: frozenlist-1.3.3-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: fsspec-2023.4.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: future-0.18.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: glob2-0.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: greenlet-2.0.1-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: heapdict-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: idna-3.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: imagesize-1.4.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: incremental-21.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: inflection-0.5.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: iniconfig-1.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: ipython_genutils-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: isort-5.9.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: itemadapter-0.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: itsdangerous-2.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jellyfish-1.0.1-py311h36a85e1_0.conda
Extract: jmespath-0.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: joblib-1.2.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: json5-0.9.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jsonpointer-2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.5-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: kiwisolver-1.4.4-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: lazy-object-proxy-1.6.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: lazy_loader-0.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: lcms2-2.12-h83e58a3_0.conda
Extract: libmamba-1.5.1-hcd6fe79_0.conda
Extract: libwebp-1.3.2-hbc33d0d_0.conda
Extract: llvmlite-0.40.0-py311hf2fb9eb_0.conda
Extract: locket-1.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: lxml-4.9.3-py311h09808a7_0.conda
Extract: lz4-4.3.2-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: markdown-3.4.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: markupsafe-2.1.1-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: mccabe-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: mdurl-0.1.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: mistune-0.8.4-py311h2bbff1b_1000.conda
Extract: mkl-service-2.4.0-py311h2bbff1b_1.conda
Extract: more-itertools-8.12.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: mpmath-1.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: msgpack-python-1.0.3-py311h59b6b97_0.conda
Extract: multidict-6.0.2-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: munkres-1.1.4-py_0.conda
Extract: mypy_extensions-1.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: nest-asyncio-1.5.6-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: networkx-3.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: openjpeg-2.4.0-h4fc8c34_0.conda
Extract: packaging-23.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pandocfilters-1.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: param-1.13.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: parso-0.8.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: pathlib-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: pathspec-0.10.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pep8-1.7.1-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: pickleshare-0.7.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1003.conda
Extract: pkce-1.0.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pkginfo-1.9.6-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: platformdirs-3.10.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pluggy-1.0.0-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: ply-3.11-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: powershell_shortcut-0.0.1-3.conda
Extract: poyo-0.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: prometheus_client-0.14.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: psutil-5.9.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: ptyprocess-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2.conda
Extract: pure_eval-0.2.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: py-cpuinfo-8.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: py-lief-0.12.3-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: pyasn1-0.4.8-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: pycodestyle-2.10.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pycosat-0.6.4-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: pycparser-2.21-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: pycurl-7.45.2-py311he2ea4bf_1.conda
Extract: pydispatcher-2.0.5-py311haa95532_2.conda
Extract: pyflakes-3.0.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pygments-2.15.1-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: pyjwt-2.4.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pylint-venv-2.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pyodbc-4.0.34-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: pyparsing-3.0.9-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pyrsistent-0.18.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: python-fastjsonschema-2.16.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: python-json-logger-2.0.7-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: python-kaleido-0.2.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: python-libarchive-c-2.9-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: python-lmdb-1.4.1-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: python-snappy-0.6.1-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: python-tzdata-2023.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: python-xxhash-2.0.2-py311h2bbff1b_1.conda
Extract: pytz-2023.3.post1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pywin32-305-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py311haa95532_1000.conda
Extract: pywinpty-2.0.10-py311h5da7b33_0.conda
Extract: pyyaml-6.0-py311h2bbff1b_1.conda
Extract: pyzmq-23.2.0-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: qdarkstyle-3.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: qt-main-5.15.2-h879a1e9_9.conda
Extract: queuelib-1.5.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: regex-2022.7.9-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: rfc3986-validator-0.1.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: rtree-1.0.1-py311h2eaa2aa_0.conda
Extract: ruamel.yaml-0.17.21-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: ruamel_yaml-0.17.21-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: safetensors-0.3.2-py311h062c2fa_0.conda
Extract: send2trash-1.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: setuptools-68.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: six-1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: smart_open-5.2.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: sniffio-1.2.0-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: snowballstemmer-2.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: sortedcontainers-2.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: soupsieve-2.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-2.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.tar.bz2
Extract: sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: tabulate-0.8.10-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: tbb4py-2021.8.0-py311h59b6b97_0.conda
Extract: tblib-1.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: tenacity-8.2.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: text-unidecode-1.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: textdistance-4.2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: threadpoolctl-2.2.0-pyh0d69192_0.conda
Extract: tokenizers-0.13.2-py311h49fca51_1.conda
Extract: toml-0.10.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: tomlkit-0.11.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: toolz-0.12.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: tornado-6.3.2-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: traitlets-5.7.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: twisted-iocpsupport-1.0.2-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: typing_extensions-4.7.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: uc-micro-py-1.0.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: ujson-5.4.0-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: unidecode-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: wcwidth-0.2.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: webencodings-0.5.1-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: whatthepatch-1.0.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: wheel-0.38.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: widgetsnbextension-4.0.5-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: wrapt-1.14.1-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: xyzservices-2022.9.0-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: y-py-0.5.9-py311hb6bf4ef_0.conda
Extract: yapf-0.31.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: zipp-3.11.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: zope-1.0-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: aioitertools-0.7.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: aiosignal-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: anyio-3.5.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: astroid-2.14.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: asttokens-2.0.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: automat-20.2.0-py_0.conda
Extract: autopep8-1.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: babel-2.11.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: backports.weakref-1.0.post1-py_1.conda
Extract: beautifulsoup4-4.12.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: binaryornot-0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: bleach-4.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: cffi-1.15.1-py311h2bbff1b_3.conda
Extract: click-8.0.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: clyent-1.2.2-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: comm-0.1.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-pack-0.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: cytoolz-0.12.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: flake8-6.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: fonttools-4.25.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: hyperlink-21.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: importlib-metadata-6.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: intervaltree-3.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jaraco.classes-3.2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jedi-0.18.1-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: jinja2-3.1.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jsonpatch-1.32-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jsonschema-4.17.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_core-5.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_ydoc-0.2.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py_0.conda
Extract: libmambapy-1.5.1-py311h77c03ed_0.conda
Extract: libthrift-0.15.0-h4364b78_2.conda
Extract: linkify-it-py-2.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: markdown-it-py-2.2.0-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: matplotlib-inline-0.1.6-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: multipledispatch-0.6.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: multiprocess-0.70.14-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: numpy-base-1.24.3-py311hd01c5d8_1.conda
Extract: openpyxl-3.0.10-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: partd-1.4.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pexpect-4.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3.conda
Extract: pillow-9.4.0-py311hd77b12b_1.conda
Extract: pip-23.2.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: plotly-5.9.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: prompt-toolkit-3.0.36-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: protego-0.1.16-py_0.conda
Extract: pyasn1-modules-0.2.8-py_0.conda
Extract: pydocstyle-6.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pysocks-1.7.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pytest-7.4.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: python-dateutil-2.8.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: python-lsp-jsonrpc-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: python-slugify-5.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: pytoolconfig-1.2.5-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: pyviz_comms-2.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: qt-webengine-5.15.9-h5bd16bc_7.conda
Extract: qtpy-2.2.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: rfc3339-validator-0.1.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: sip-6.6.2-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: sqlalchemy-1.4.39-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: sympy-1.11.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: terminado-0.17.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: three-merge-0.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: tinycss2-1.2.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: tqdm-4.65.0-py311h746a85d_0.conda
Extract: typing-extensions-4.7.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: w3lib-1.21.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: watchdog-2.1.6-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: websocket-client-0.58.0-py311haa95532_4.conda
Extract: werkzeug-2.2.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: xlwings-0.29.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: yarl-1.8.1-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: ypy-websocket-0.8.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: zict-2.2.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: zope.interface-5.4.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: aiohttp-3.8.5-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: arrow-1.2.3-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: arrow-cpp-11.0.0-ha81ea56_2.conda
Extract: backports.tempfile-1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1.tar.bz2
Extract: bcrypt-3.2.0-py311h2bbff1b_1.conda
Extract: black-23.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: brotlipy-0.7.0-py311h2bbff1b_1002.conda
Extract: cryptography-41.0.3-py311h89fc84f_0.conda
Extract: dask-core-2023.6.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: flask-2.2.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: importlib_metadata-6.0.0-hd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_client-7.4.9-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_events-0.6.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: mdit-py-plugins-0.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: nbformat-5.9.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: nltk-3.8.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: parsel-1.6.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: prompt_toolkit-3.0.36-hd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: pydantic-1.10.8-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: pylint-2.16.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pynacl-1.5.0-py311h8cc25b3_0.conda
Extract: pyqt5-sip-12.11.0-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: python-dotenv-0.21.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: qstylizer-0.2.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: qtawesome-1.2.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: qtwebkit-5.212-h2bbfb41_5.conda
Extract: rope-1.7.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: stack_data-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: zstandard-0.19.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: argon2-cffi-21.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: conda-content-trust-0.2.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-package-streaming-0.9.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: ipython-8.15.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: itemloaders-1.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: jinja2-time-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3.conda
Extract: keyring-23.13.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: nbclient-0.5.13-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: paramiko-2.8.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: pyopenssl-23.2.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pyqt-5.15.7-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: python-lsp-server-1.7.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: service_identity-18.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
Extract: conda-package-handling-2.2.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: ipykernel-6.25.0-py311h746a85d_0.conda
Extract: nbconvert-6.5.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pyls-spyder-0.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: pyqtwebengine-5.15.7-py311hd77b12b_0.conda
Extract: python-lsp-black-1.2.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: twisted-22.10.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: urllib3-1.26.16-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: botocore-1.29.76-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-verify-3.4.2-py_1.conda
Extract: distributed-2023.6.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: ipywidgets-8.0.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_console-6.6.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_server-1.23.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: qtconsole-5.4.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: requests-2.31.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: spyder-kernels-2.4.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: aiobotocore-2.5.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: anaconda-cloud-auth-0.1.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-23.7.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: cookiecutter-1.7.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: huggingface_hub-0.15.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_server_fileid-0.9.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyterlab_server-2.22.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: notebook-shim-0.2.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pyct-0.5.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: requests-file-1.5.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: requests-toolbelt-1.0.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: responses-0.13.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: sphinx-5.0.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: anaconda-client-1.12.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: colorcet-3.0.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-index-0.3.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-libmamba-solver-23.7.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-token-0.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: jupyter_server_ydoc-0.8.0-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: navigator-updater-0.4.0-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: nbclassic-0.5.5-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: numpydoc-1.5.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: s3fs-2023.4.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: tldextract-3.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
Extract: anaconda-project-0.11.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-build-3.26.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: conda-repo-cli-1.0.75-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: notebook-6.5.4-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: scrapy-2.8.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: spyder-5.4.3-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: anaconda-navigator-2.5.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyterlab-3.6.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: jupyter-1.0.0-py311haa95532_8.conda
Extract: anaconda-catalogs-0.2.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: bottleneck-1.3.5-py311h5bb9823_0.conda
Extract: contourpy-1.0.5-py311h59b6b97_0.conda
Extract: daal4py-2023.1.1-py311h30df693_0.conda
Extract: datashape-0.5.4-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: h5py-3.9.0-py311h4e0e482_0.conda
Extract: imagecodecs-2023.1.23-py311he6ff3c7_0.conda
Extract: imageio-2.26.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: intake-0.6.8-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: matplotlib-3.7.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: matplotlib-base-3.7.2-py311hf62ec03_0.conda
Extract: mkl_fft-1.3.8-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: mkl_random-1.2.4-py311h59b6b97_0.conda
Extract: numpy-1.24.3-py311hdab7c0b_1.conda
Extract: numba-0.57.1-py311hf62ec03_0.conda
Extract: numexpr-2.8.4-py311h1fcbade_1.conda
Extract: patsy-0.5.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: pyarrow-11.0.0-py311h8a3a540_1.conda
Extract: pyerfa-2.0.0-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: pywavelets-1.4.1-py311h2bbff1b_0.conda
Extract: scipy-1.11.1-py311hc1ccb85_0.conda
Extract: tifffile-2023.4.12-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: astropy-5.1-py311h5bb9823_0.conda
Extract: gensim-4.3.0-py311heda8569_0.conda
Extract: pandas-2.0.3-py311hf62ec03_0.conda
Extract: pytables-3.8.0-py311h4671533_3.conda
Extract: scikit-image-0.20.0-py311h3513d60_0.conda
Extract: scikit-learn-1.3.0-py311hf62ec03_0.conda
Extract: bokeh-3.2.1-py311h746a85d_0.conda
Extract: datasets-2.12.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: imbalanced-learn-0.10.1-py311haa95532_1.conda
Extract: scikit-learn-intelex-2023.1.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: seaborn-0.12.2-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: statsmodels-0.14.0-py311hd7041d2_0.conda
Extract: xarray-2023.6.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: dask-2023.6.0-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: datashader-0.15.2-py311haa95532_0.tar.bz2
Extract: panel-1.2.3-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: transformers-4.32.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: holoviews-1.17.1-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: hvplot-0.8.4-py311haa95532_0.conda
Extract: anaconda_depends-2023.09-py311_mkl_1.conda
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3\pkgs
Extract: env.txt
Output folder: C:\Users\MOE_LIDAR\anaconda3_\conda-meta
Extract: history
Error loading Python DLL ‘C:\Users\MOE_LI~1\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI40762\python39.dll’.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Windows 7 support ended on January 14, 2020.

[Release-notes](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/reference/release-notes/#id73) of anaconda are stating Anaconda 2020.02 (March 11, 2020) as being the `Last official release to support Windows 7`.

I don't know how you managed to install newer versions of Anaconda on Windows 7 Computers after that, but even if you succeeded, expect more and more recent packages to not work properly (or at all) on Windows 7 machines.
The 2023 release of Anaconda is NOT expected to install on Windows 7.

Comment: Ah I had no idea, guess I was getting lucky up until this point. Thank you!